# Has anyone had problems with identical controls working on a top level webpage, but not a lower-level webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, drop-down-menu

I apologize if this is not a proper question, but I am new to StackOverflow, so here goes...

I am programming in C# for the web in VS2005 (at the company I work for; I use VS2012 at home), and have written a somewhat lengthy program for work.

My problem is that I can add certain controls on the master/home page, such as a nested gridview or even a simple dropdownlist, and they work better than beautifully. When I add the exact same control, with the same SQL data source, to a lower-level webpage, they refuse to work. The SQL data loads just fine, but the SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedIndexChanging methods don't work. Yes, I have checked everything from AutoPostBack=true to the ViewState=true.

Oddly enough, almost every page (20+) in the program has at least one regular gridview, and they work like a charm on every page. I have not yet coded a regular gridview that has NOT worked.

Comment: Oddly enough, I got the dropdownlist to work, in a fashion. But it's not an acceptable solution. It was suggested to me by a co-worker to use a listbox instead, so I did. That control's SelectedIndexChanged doesn't work either. But on a whim, I went straight from the non-working listbox and chose an item in my dropdownlist, clicked the "save to SQL" button, and the dropdownlist selection worked! I have no idea why.

Comment: The code in my program concerning these controls is really very simple - I load data from a SQL table into the control (dropdownlist or listbox). When an item in either list is selected, it (is supposed to) save that value to a session variable. Then when the "save" button is clicked, it saves that value along with other information to another SQL table. I might add that when I enter the information manually through a textbox, it works perfectly every time.